# Implement discontinuous bar chart with D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to create a design that looks like below. I wonder whether I could use d3 making x-axis as time zone and hide the y-axis and show the time slots as given below in the image.

TIA

[image: [1]]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use x scale for determining rectangle's x coordinate and width.
2. Use y scale for locating rectangle's y coordinate and height.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

.bar { fill: steelblue; }

</style>
<body>
 
<!-- load the d3.js library -->     
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, height])
          .padding(0.1);
          
// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data = [
    {"name" : "Bob", "start" : 0, "end" : 5},
    {"name" : "Robin", "start" : 6, "end" : 7},
    {"name" : "Anne", "start" : 7, "end" : 9},
    {"name" : "Mark", "start" : 9, "end" : 14}
];

    x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.end; })]);
    y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
    
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.start); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { 
        return x(d.end) - x(d.start) })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) { 
        return y(d.name); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y.bandwidth(); });
    
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisTop(x));
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

</script>
</body>
```